# Angular 11 PWA not loading components in production

Tags: angular

I have an PWA application built in Angular 11. Everthing works well locally, however in production the components do not get loaded.

This is what I am doing to test the app locally.

ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer

http-server-spa dist/my-app/ index.html 4200

Structure of the build folder dist/my-app (all files are inside of the my-app sub folder)

I can see the  from index.html loaded correctly, however components inside of app.component.html are not getting loaded.

I can see the component name under elements in the Developer console but nothing gets loaded.

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There are no error messages.

Comment: If you disable your service worker does your app load normally in production?

Comment: Can you provide more context as to the way you're trying to load these components?

Comment: I finally resolved it, I had to change my build command to this: ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing=media --sourceMap=true --extract-css=false --buildOptimizer=false. Although I am still unsure why aot=false etc.